# Can we access Data from ADLA tables creating ODATA source using REST API?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is there a way if ODATA can be established on top of azure data lake analytics table via REST API's?
It seems there are REST API's to get ADLA job informations, account information etc.,
Is there any such existing API's to get data or is it possible to create API to access data via ODATA concept?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access data in ADLS files, there are REST APIs to get data from the lake. ADLS supports WebHDFS APIs with OAuth.

If you want to send queries and see their results or get U-SQL table data, you would have to write your own shim that translates the query you submit via your API into a U-SQL Script that outputs a file and then transparently download the file and returns it as the result.

Note that so-called interactive support is on the roadmap and being worked on. Once that is available, you can access the data using standard query APIs (such as ODBC, JDBC etc).